# "snakemake: error: unrecognized arguments:"

Tags: python, config, slurm, snakemake

I am working to implement a snakemake pipeline on our university's HPC. I am doing so in an activated conda environment and with the following script submitted using sbatch:

```sh
snakemake --dryrun --summary --jobs 100 --use-conda -p \
 --configfile config.yaml --cluster-config cluster.yaml \
 --profile /path/to/conda/env --cluster "sbatch --parsable \
 --qos=unlim --partition={cluster.queue} \
 --job-name=username.{rule}.{wildcards} --mem={cluster.mem}gb \
 --time={cluster.time} --ntasks={cluster.threads} \
 --nodes={cluster.nodes}"
```

config.yaml

```
metaG_accession: PRJNA766694
metaG_ena_table: /home/etucker5/miniconda3/envs/s-niv-MAGs/data/input/ENA_tables/PRJNA766694_metaG_wenv.txt

inputDIR: /home/etucker5/miniconda3/envs/s-niv-MAGs/data/input
outputDIR: /home/etucker5/miniconda3/envs/s-niv-MAGs/data/output

scratch: /home/etucker5/miniconda3/envs/s-niv-MAGs/data/scratch
adapters: /home/etucker5/miniconda3/envs/s-niv-MAGs/data/input/adapters/illumina-adapters.fa
metaG_sample_list: /home/etucker5/miniconda3/envs/s-niv-MAGs/data/input/SampleList_ForAssembly_metaG.txt

megahit_other: --continue --k-list 29,39,59,79,99,119
megahit_cpu: 80
megahit_min_contig: 1000
megahit_mem: 0.95
restart-times: 0
max-jobs-per-second: 1
max-status-checks-per-secon: 10
local-cores: 1
rerun-incomplete: true
keep-going: true
```

Snakefile

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

import io
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pathlib
from snakemake.exceptions import print_exception, WorkflowError

#----SET VARIABLES----#
METAG_ACCESSION = config["metaG_accession"]
METAG_SAMPLES = pd.read_table(config["metaG_ena_table"])
INPUTDIR = config["inputDIR"]
ADAPTERS = config["adapters"]
SCRATCHDIR = config["scratch"]
OUTPUTDIR = config["outputDIR"]
METAG_SAMPLELIST = pd.read_table(config["metaG_sample_list"], index_col="Assembly_group")
METAG_ASSEMBLYGROUP = list(METAG_SAMPLELIST.index)
ASSEMBLYGROUP = METAG_ASSEMBLYGROUP

#----COMPUTE VAR----#
MEGAHIT_CPU = config["megahit_cpu"]
MEGAHIT_MIN_CONTIG = config["megahit_min_contig"]
MEGAHIT_MEM = config["megahit_mem"]
MEGAHIT_OTHER = config["megahit_other"]
```

and slurm error output

```
snakemake: error: unrecognized arguments: --metaG_accession=PRJNA766694
--metaG_ena_table=/home/etucker5/miniconda3/envs/s-niv-MAGs/data/input/ENA_tables/PRJNA766694_metaG_wenv.txt
--inputDIR=/home/etucker5/miniconda3/envs/s-niv-MAGs/data/input
--outputDIR=/home/etucker5/miniconda3/envs/s-niv-MAGs/data/output
--scratch=/home/etucker5/miniconda3/envs/s-niv-MAGs/data/scratch
--adapters=/home/etucker5/miniconda3/envs/s-niv-MAGs/data/input/adapters/illumina-adapters.fa
--metaG_sample_list=/home/etucker5/miniconda3/envs/s-niv-MAGs/data/input/SampleList_ForAssembly_metaG.txt
--megahit_cpu=80 --megahit_min_contig=1000 --megahit_mem=0.95
```

On execution it fails to recognize arguments in my config.yaml file (for ex.):

`snakemake: error: unrecognized arguments: --inputDIR=[path\to\dir]`

In my understanding the Snakefile should be able to take any arguments stated in the config.yaml using:

`INPUTDIR = config["inputDIR"]`

when:

`configfile: "config.yaml"`

is input in my Snakefile.

Also, my config.yaml properly recognizes non-custom arguments such as:

`max-jobs-per-second: 1`

Is there some custom library setup that I need to initiate for this particular config.yaml? This is my first time using Snakemake and I am still learning how to properly work with config files.

Also, on swapping the paths directly into the Snakefile I was able to get the summary output for my dryrun without the unrecognized arguments error.

Comment: If this is your first time using Snakemake, try not to overcomplicate things. First try to get it to run locally, not on `slurm`. What happens if you get rid of all the slurm stuff and try it locally? What's the full stacktrace you get? Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? You've just shown your snakemake bash command, not Snakefile nor config.yaml. It's hard to help you like that.

Comment: Also your title doesn't make much sense, it ends cryptically: `"snakemake: error: unrecognized arguments:" for custom` for custom what?

Comment: In addition to @CorneliusRoemer: Post the snakemake command you executed (if different from above); post the full error from snakemake, copy and paste from your terminal without editing; show the part of the Snakefile where you access `config["inputDIR"]` and the content of `config.yaml`. Unless this information is really large or contains sensitive data, it's better to post more rather than less.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer I did just get it run by swapping the path names in directly for the config['path'] that was in my original Snakefile. I've added the config and partial Snakefile in my original post.

Comment: @dariober just added a bit more content to help describe the problem.

Comment: @BHapi can you take all the slurm stuff? You're asking for trouble by trying something complicated (cluster) when you're new to Snakemake. Try simple (local) first.
So is this a cluster problem only or not? I'm confused by the way you write your question. Does the path `/home/etucker5` exist on the cluster?

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer Yes, I was able to complete a dry-run on the cluster by giving the direct path, rather than using config['']. The path /home/etucker5 does exist on the cluster.

Comment: Feel free to write that as an answer so that people can think of that as a potential solution in the future

Comment: @BHapi, you are correct that you should be able to access values with `config["inputDir"]`. The error you are getting is coming from some other complicating factor. First, of all, I would follow @CorneliusRoemer's suggestion to not use SLRUM while you're debugging. Second, if hard coding the values solves your problem, try printing out the values you get from the config to make sure they are correct. For example: follow the line `INPUTDIR = config["inputDIR"]` with `print("INPUTDIR is ", INPUTDIR)`

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the way in which the workflow was executed using Slurm. I had been executing snakemake with sbatch as a bash script.

Instead, snakemake can be executed directly through the terminal or using bash. While I'm not exactly sure why, this caused my jobs to run on the cluster's local, which has tight memory limits, rather than on the hpc partitions that have appropriate capacity. Executing it this way also caused snakemake to not recognize the paths set in my config.yaml.

The lesson learned is that snakemake has a built in way of communicating with the slurm manager and it seems that executing snakemake through sbatch will cause conflicts.

```
("Conda Env") [user@log001 "Main Directory"]$ snakemake   \
>         --jobs 100 --use-conda -p -s Snakefile  \
>         --cluster-config cluster.yaml --cluster "sbatch \
> --parsable --qos=unlim --partition={cluster.queue} \
> --job-name=TARA.{rule}.{wildcards} --mem={cluster.mem}gb \
> --time={cluster.time} --ntasks={cluster.threads} --nodes={cluster.nodes}"
```